# How do I search string for a pattern?

Tags: php, string

I'm searching a string for a certain pattern.

```
$string = "Monday: 08.00-18.00";
$pattern = "xx.xx-xx.xx";
```

The "x" could be "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8" or "9".
The "-" must be a "-".
The "." could be "." or ":".

Is there a way to this this?

Comment: Have you looked at regexpressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like

```
$string = "Monday: 08.00-18.00";
$pattern = "/[0-9]{2}[:|\.][0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{2}[:|\.][0-9]{2}/";
if(preg_match($pattern,$string,$matches))
{
    // has the pattern, do something
    //$matches has all the matches from preg_match
    echo $matches[0]; // prints the matched pattern
}
```

Comment: Thx! But it does not seem to work. The function return false. Same for  MichaelRushtons example..

Comment: Try it again. Forgot to add $matches to preg_match and the pattern was incorrect in the [:|.]. I've tested it and worked. I believe that the problem with MichaelRushton pattern is that doesn't have ("|" meaning "or") in the [:.]. and that "^" means that the string starts there and the "$" is the end of the string. So his pattern is looking for a string that is exactly like that (08.00-18.00) but in your case you can have something at the beginning (like: "Monday:") and/or something at the end.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).
Replace x with `[0-9]`.
Replace . with `[.:]`.

Comment: The `.` in your `(.:)` will match any character (except the newline, unless the `s` modifier is set).

Comment: Okey! Although I'm new to PCRE patterns. I would very much appreciate an example of such a function.

Comment: @MichaelRushton: Thanks for noticing that. I have corrected it:)

Comment: @Michael: vasen and MichaelRushton created great working examples:)

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you need:

```
preg_match('/^[0-9]{2}[:.][0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}[:.][0-9]{2}$/D', $string)
```